# Subtract Timestamps in laravel with Carbon giving error

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm Trying to subtract 2 timestamps with Carbon but i'm getting error : 
"InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425:
Hour can not be higher than 12 "

```
$s = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
     $lastlog = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('y-m-d h:m:i',  '16-09-19 14:10:11');
       $h = $lastlog->diffForHumans($s);
```

i have also tried

```
  $s = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
     $lastlog = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('y-m-d h:m:i',  '16-09-19 14:10:11');
 $lastlog = date('y-m-d a h:m:i' , strtotime($lastlog));
 $h = $lastlog->diffForHumans($s);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date format for 24-hour times is H, not h: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

So you want

```
 $lastlog = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('y-m-d H:m:i',  '16-09-19 14:10:11');
```